# multiple lines each based on a different dataframe in ggplot2 - automatic coloring and legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have the following data frames:

```
df1 = data.frame(c11 = c(1:5), c12 = c(1:5))
df2 = data.frame(c21 = c(1:5), c22 = (c(1:5))^0.5)
df3 = data.frame(c31 = c(1:5), c32 = (c(1:5))^2)
```

I want to plot these as lines in the same plot/panel. I can do this by

```
p <- ggplot() + geom_line(data=df1, aes(x=c11, y = c12)) + 
     geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=c21,y=c22)) + 
     geom_line(data=df3, aes(x=c31, c32))
```

All these will be black. If I want them in a different color, I can specify the color explicitly as an argument to `geom_line()`. My question is can I specify a list of a few colors, say 5 colors, such as, red, blue, green, orange, gray, and use that list so that I do not have to explicitly specify the colors as an argument to geom_line() in case of each line. If the plot `p` contains 2 geom_line() statements then it will color them red and blue respectively. If it contains 3 geom_line statements, it will color them red, blue and green. Finally, how can I specify the legend for these plots. Even if I can give the colors as a vector at the end of `p` that would be great. Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ggplot2 works best if you work with a melted data.frame that contains a different column to specify the different aesthetics. Melting is easier with common column names, so I'd start there. Here are the steps I'd take:

- rename the columns
- melt the data which adds a new variables that we'll map to the colour aesthetic
- define your colour vector
- Specify the appropriate scale with scale_colour_manual

'

```
names(df1) <- c("x", "y")
names(df2) <- c("x", "y")
names(df3) <- c("x", "y")

newData <- melt(list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3), id.vars = "x")

#Specify your colour vector
cols <- c("red", "blue", "green", "orange", "gray")

#Plot data and specify the manual scale
ggplot(newData, aes(x, value, colour = L1)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols)
```

**Edited for clarity**

The structure of `newData`:

```
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ x       : int  1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 1 level "y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value   : num  1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ L1      : chr  "df1" "df1" "df1" "df1" ...
```

And the plot itself:

[image]

Comment: @Chase. Thanks! However, the example you have given plots a single line, not three different lines. I suppose I can take care of that by adding `group = L1` as an argument to `aes()`. The problem with that is the legend. Can you please try? The legend does not make sense. The legend has more than three keys in it.

Comment: @Curious - What's the structure of your real data? Running the code above yields three lines with a legend that makes intuitive sense to me...I'll update my answer with the str of `newData` and give the plot I'm seeing. Not sure why you'd be getting something else unless your data isn't representative of your example data. You could force L1 to be a factor if needed, though that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Chase. Thanks for the clarification. For some reason, the L1 variable in my case is an `int` (1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 etc.) and not `chr`. If I correct that, it works. Now I need to figure out how to change the legend title and names. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Curious - I can duplicate those results if I don't give the list objects names in the call to `melt()`. I gave each data.frame a name...`df1 = df1`, you could name them whatever you want...`foo = df1, bar = df2, baz = df3`. If you don't name them, then they are just assigned integer values. Legend title can be changed with `scale_colour_manual(name = "yahtzee", ...)`. I'd set the names to what you want when you melt the data.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying this. Now I understand it. One quick question: I can also set legend title (at least in this case) by `scale_color_hue()` instead of `scale_color_manual()`. Is one better than the other? Once again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Chase - Just wanted to let you know that `scale_color_manual` did not work? I had to use `scale_color_hue`. Thanks anyway for the explanation about setting the key label names when melting data.

Comment: @Chase Useful solution.  Can it can be adapted for adding a fitted-model line to a *point* plot?  I tried to adapt a standard R plot() technique for adding curved lines (see the link below: the last 2 pages refer) to ggplot2 using this melt process, but of course ended up with lines representing the original point data. Am I'm going about this in the wrong way? [link](http://www.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~kvansteen/GBIO0009-1/ac20092010/Class8/Using%20R%20for%20linear%20regression.pdf)

Comment: @geotheory - yep, that shouldn't be much of a problem at all. `ggplot2` has specific geoms for points and another one that fits a model of your choosing to your data. To adopt the data above to show an xy scatterplot with an abline from the linear model would be `geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")`. Check out the [ggplot2 website](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) for more details on the different geoms available.

Comment: You get a single line if you melt a list without names

Answer (score 13):

You dont have to melt, group or gather. Its pretty simple. Just add the color to the geom_line

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 = data.frame(c11 = c(1:5), c12 = c(1:5))
df2 = data.frame(c21 = c(1:5), c22 = (c(1:5))^0.5)
df3 = data.frame(c31 = c(1:5), c32 = (c(1:5))^2)

p <- ggplot() + geom_line(data=df1, aes(x=c11, y = c12), color= "red") + 
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=c21,y=c22), color = "blue") + 
  geom_line(data=df3, aes(x=c31, c32), color = "green")
p
```

[image: The result plot]

Answer (score 7):

These sorts of questions become much easier to solve if you adjust your thinking to the way that `ggplot2` approaches graphics. `ggplot2` is organized around the idea that everything that appears in your graph should (in principle) exist as a column in your data frame. (There are exceptions, of course, but this is the general idea.)

So your attempt to build this graph piece by piece, one line at a time, each coming from different data frames and *then* assigning colors to them is very un-`ggplot2`ish. If you want to label things in your graph with different colors, your first thought should always be:

> How can I encode this color labeling information as a *variable*?

In this case, the solution is fairly simple. Simply `rbind` your three data frames together (you'll need to make sure the colnames match up first) and create a new column, say `grp` that has three levels corresponding to your three data frames:

```
dat <- rbind(df1,df2,df3)
dat$grp <- rep(factor(1:3),times = c(nrow(df1),nrow(df2),nrow(df3)))
```

and then *map* the *variable* `grp` to the *aesthetic* color in the ggplot call:

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x=...,y=...,colour = grp) + 
    geom_line()
```

Finally, if you don't like the default colors, you can specify your own using `scale_colour_manual`:

```
+ scale_colour_manual(value = c('green','blue','grey'))
```

or you can use some nice 'pre-chosen' palettes from `scale_colour_brewer`.

EDIT: I fixed a typo above to ensure that `grp` is a factor. Here's my final version:

```
df1 = data.frame(c1 = c(1:5), c2 = c(1:5))
df2 = data.frame(c1 = c(1:5), c2 = (c(1:5))^0.5)
df3 = data.frame(c1 = c(1:5), c2 = (c(1:5))^2)

dat <- rbind(df1,df2,df3)
dat$grp <- rep(factor(1:3),times=c(nrow(df1),nrow(df2),nrow(df3)))

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = c1, y = c2, colour = grp)) + 
    geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried many approaches for this, none of which really worked, After this reframe of my thinking, I get much simpler ways to construct plots.