# Print processed data from multiple CSV files

Tags: r, excel, csv

I want to process data from an Excel file with 29 worksheets. The Excel file is subdivided into 29 CSV files.

The code that I made gave me an Excel document with just one row for all 29 worksheets. I need to print a summary for each (loaded) worksheet (in the end 29 rows).

```
for (i in 1:length(list.filenames))
{
    list.data[[i]]<-read.csv(list.filenames[i])
    cdata <- ddply(list.data[[i]], c("Year"), summarise, God.Padavine = sum(PRECIPITATION),  N    = length(PRECIPITATION), mean = mean(PRECIPITATION),  sd   = sd(PRECIPITATION), se   = sd *100/mean)
    cdata111 <- ddply(cdata, c(), summarise, God.Padavine1 = sum(God.Padavine)/70,  N    = length(God.Padavine), mean = mean(God.Padavine),  sd   = sd(God.Padavine), se   = sd *100/mean)
    write.xlsx(x = cdata111, file = "test.excelfile111.xlsx", sheetName = "TestSheet", row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Maybe edit your post. Use a minimal example instead of your whole code. It is not quite clear what you are looking for. In general for working with Excel in R I recommend you to use `openxlsx`.

Comment: I have 29 CSV files, and the program in the new Excel file only writes the value from the last CSV file. I would like to include in my code and the new Excel file all the data from each CSV file. The question is: how to make an Excel file a row of rows from each procured CSV file

Comment: I realised I forgot the guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

The problem with your code is that you overwrite your xlsx. You only loop through the first two lines of code.

Comment: It looks like it works overwrite .. How can I make every posting of data from a dataframe into each row of Excel table of a sheet, and so 29 times. In the Excel table, it should add row to row, and he seems to only write in the first row and afterwards only the data from the last sheet

Comment: Matrix result after for loops has all 0 elements!!! This is problem!!!

Comment: Sorry but it is impossible (for me and others) to help you if you don't provide proper sample data like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525864/multiple-lines-each-based-on-a-different-dataframe-in-ggplot2-automatic-colori?rq=1). What I did so far was a guess. Which is more than I should have done.

Comment: Year MONTH_ID PRECIPITATION
1946 1 27
1946 2 38
1946 3 11
1946 4 26
1946 5 51
1946 6 79
1946 7 1
1946 8 19
1946 9 6
1946 10 76
1946 11 51
1946 12 28
1947 1 54
1947 2 24
1947 3 33
1947 4 30
1947 5 36
1947 6 45
1947 7 52
1947 8 97
1947 9 1
1947 10 23
1947 11 34
1947 12 56   and other year and data...for one CSV file...

Comment: So each CSV file has YEAR, MONTH and PRECIPITATION as columns? How many years does each CSV-file have? Does that differ or is it always two years like 1946,1947 in your example. 

So far there is two things possible: First I can bind the `cdata`-object from all 29 csv-files together in one matrix/file. Secondly I can create a matrix, which contains an object like `cdata111` for each csv-file. Is either one what you are looking for?

Comment: Every CSV file for years has been from 1945-2015. Mont_ID refers to the number of months. The third column refers to precipitation. Your previous solution is well done, but it's 29 sheets in an Excel document, and I would like to get one sheet of 29 rows in the table for each CSV that is loaded through the FOR loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a super busy week, so I only managed to look over your problem now. Hope this answer will still prove useful to you:

```
### 1. Create some example data
example_data=data.frame(Year=rep(1946:1947,each=12),MONTH_ID=rep(1:12,2),PRECIPITATION=round(runif(24,1,100)))
example_data2=data.frame(Year=rep(1948,12),MONTH_ID=1:12,PRECIPITATION=round(runif(12,1,100)))
example_data3=data.frame(Year=rep(1949:1951,each=12),MONTH_ID=rep(1:12,3),PRECIPITATION=round(runif(36,1,100)))
list.data=list(example_data,example_data2,example_data3)

### 2. Loop through the list of data 
cdata=cdata111=list(1:2)
for (i in 1:length(list.data)){                         # replaced list.filenames since I made sample data
    #list.data[[i]]<-read.csv(list.filenames[i])        # Not used because I created sample data
    cdata[[i]] <- ddply(list.data[[i]], c("Year"), summarise, God.Padavine = sum(PRECIPITATION),  N    = length(PRECIPITATION), mean = mean(PRECIPITATION),  sd   = sd(PRECIPITATION), se   = sd *100/mean)
    cdata111[[i]] <- ddply(cdata[[i]], c(), summarise, God.Padavine1 = sum(God.Padavine)/70,  N    = length(God.Padavine), mean = mean(God.Padavine),  sd   = sd(God.Padavine), se   = sd *100/mean)
}

### 3. Write the results
input_summary<-do.call(rbind,cdata111)
yrly_summary<-do.call(rbind,cdata)
write.xlsx(input_summary, file = "Input_summary.xlsx", sheetName = "Input_summary", row.names = FALSE)
```

For future projects note that there were two issues with your code: Firstly you did not loop through `cdata111` and secondly you used the `write.xlsx`-function inside the loop. Especially the latter is bad practise, because it will slow down your code dramatically. If you ever want to do such a thing use `openxlsx` and write the xlsx **after** the loop.

If you store all the results of a loop in a list, you can use `do.call(rbind,mylist)` to bind all the individual list together by row. Of course for this the columns need to be the same over every list item.

Comment: @Miljan Jeremic I also made an edit to your question. Hope if/when it gets approved there might be more answers

Comment: Dear colleague, thank you for your help so far, I learned a lot from your examples.

I uploaded a document on my site. The document is in XLSX format.

If you do not have the problem to look at the dataframe what the document looks like, because I want to get total values in cities in one worksheet, these are 29 worksheets. Each name for the worksheet is one city with data from the years 1946-2015.
Link: https://midusware.wordpress.com/stackoverflow/
If you can also see these complete details ...

Thanks for your reply!!!

Comment: you can use the same algorithm for the data set in the link. Then you have each regional dataset in `list.data` after loading. After `list.data` you end the loop and do `tmp <- do.call(cbind, lapply(list.data, function(x) x[,-(1:2)]))`. Then you add the Month and year data with `alldata <- cbind(list.data[[1]][,1:2], tmp)`. Done!