# Assigning colors to multiple lines and adding a legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I successfully created multiple line plots on a single plot using ggplot. However, I am having difficulty adjusting the colors for each line, and then creating/formatting a legend corresponding to these colors. First, here is the data that I am working with (contained in four separate data frames):

```
newdata<-data.frame(RCP1pctCO2cumulative, Column) #length 140
newdata1<-data.frame(RCP8.5cumulative, Column1) #length 90
newdata2<-data.frame(RCP4.5cumulative, Column2) #length 90
newdata3<-data.frame(Historicalcumulative, Column3) #length 145

head(newdata) 

RCP1pctCO2cumulative   Column
layer.1          0.000000000 30.62975
layer.2          0.006974906 30.29012
layer.3          0.013907599 30.43212
layer.4          0.021697436 30.70810
layer.5          0.030232970 30.38155
layer.6          0.038998084 30.34130

head(newdata1)

RCP8.5cumulative  Column1
layer.1        0.4475691 31.94422
layer.2        0.4569296 31.93002
layer.3        0.4663113 31.98923
layer.4        0.4756628 32.16458
layer.5        0.4850761 32.20246
layer.6        0.4946258 32.16779

head(newdata2)

RCP4.5cumulative  Column2
layer.1        0.4487829 32.05137
layer.2        0.4584334 32.01951
layer.3        0.4680946 32.04347
layer.4        0.4777492 32.23928
layer.5        0.4875477 32.61044
layer.6        0.4974490 32.14446

head(newdata3)

Historicalcumulative  Column3
layer.1         0.0000000000 30.20725
layer.2         0.0009499752 30.30651
layer.3         0.0017818766 30.35118
layer.4         0.0025179833 30.13334
layer.5         0.0031186696 30.14842
layer.6         0.0036720898 29.87103
```

I tried the following:

```
gg<-ggplot(newdata, aes(x=RCP1pctCO2cumulative, y=Column)) + 
geom_smooth(), color="black")

gg + geom_smooth(data=newdata1, aes(x=RCP4.5cumulative, y=Column1)) + 
geom_smooth(data=newdata2, aes(x=RCP8.5cumulative, y=Column2)) + 
geom_smooth(data=newdata3, aes(x=Historicalcumulative, y=Column3)), 
color="red", size=3)
```

This yields this error:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "gg + geom_smooth(data=newdata1, 
aes(x=RCP4.5cumulative, y=Column1)) + geom_smooth(data=newdata2, 
aes(x=RCP8.5cumulative, y=Column2)) + geom_smooth(data=newdata3, 
aes(x=Historicalcumulative, y="
```

I know that there is a comma placed incorrectly somewhere, but I suspect that will not correct the overall problem of trying to assign specific colors to each line plot. Ideally, for "gg", I would like that line to be "green", while for the second, third and fourth lines, I want those to be "blue", "red" and "black", respectively. Then, I want to show and be able to format this in a legend, showing what each color represents.

Any help with this would be extremely valuable! It seems straight-forward, but I think the problem is related to where the "color" command needs to be placed for each line plot, and then constructing a legend.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the comma issue (and then let me know if the rest works out!)

```
gg<-ggplot(newdata, aes(x=RCP1pctCO2cumulative, y=Column)) + 
geom_smooth(color="#000000")

gg + geom_smooth(data=newdata1, aes(x=RCP4.5cumulative, y=Column1)) + 
geom_smooth(data=newdata2, aes(x=RCP8.5cumulative, y=Column2)) + 
geom_smooth(data=newdata3, aes(x=Historicalcumulative, y=Column3), 
color="red", size=3)
```

In case I misunderstood your data, here is an example using the famous Iris data:

```
ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
geom_smooth(color="#000000") + 
geom_smooth(data=iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width), color="#FF0000", size=3)
```

To get a legend, by far the easiest way is presented in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6526160/1594060). This gist of it is, use `melt` from `reshape2` to get all values into one dataframe with a categorical variable that determines color.

Comment: Hi Josh Rumbut   Thank you so very much for this!!! I was able to change the coloring of all line plots based on your first example above! In addition to Jon Spring's suggestion above, if I wanted to create and format a legend based on these colors, is there a way to accomplish that? For example, if I wanted to show that the black curve corresponds to "Historical", would that be possible to do? Thanks, again!

Comment: @Android17 I just edited in a link to a question that I believe has a pretty directly translatable piece of code for the legend part, let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: Hi Josh Rumbut This worked very well - thank you! As a last question, I am trying to write in x, y and title labels but am receiving errors and was hoping you could tell me what is causing them:

ggplot(newestdata, aes(x,value,colour=L1)) + geom_smooth() + scale_color_manual(values=cols) + theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line() + ggtitle("Global model mean one-day maximum precipitation for various scenarios"))
Error in element_line() + ggtitle("Global model mean one-day maximum precipitation for various scenarios") : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: @Android17 Looks like you are missing a `)` after `element_line()`, try `theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line())`

Comment: Hi Josh Rumbut Yes, that worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Android17 glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: using OP data**

Getting a legend set up in ggplot for data from multiple tables will be much easier if you can combine them into one table with common variables, where the source table is noted in another variable.

```
library(tidyverse)
# Convenience function to rename columns to something uniform
make_uniform <- function(df, sourcename) {
  df %>%
    rename(x = 2, y = 3) %>% # Rename 2nd and 3rd columns
    mutate(source = sourcename)
}

combined <- bind_rows(
  RCP1pctCO2cumulative %>% make_uniform("CO2"),
  RCP8.5cumulative     %>% make_uniform("RCP8.5"), 
  RCP4.5cumulative     %>% make_uniform("RCP4.5"), 
)

> combined
   rowname           x        y source
1  layer.1 0.000000000 30.62975    CO2
2  layer.2 0.006974906 30.29012    CO2
3  layer.3 0.013907599 30.43212    CO2
4  layer.4 0.021697436 30.70810    CO2
5  layer.5 0.030232970 30.38155    CO2
6  layer.6 0.038998084 30.34130    CO2
7  layer.1 0.447569100 31.94422 RCP8.5
8  layer.2 0.456929600 31.93002 RCP8.5
9  layer.3 0.466311300 31.98923 RCP8.5
10 layer.4 0.475662800 32.16458 RCP8.5
11 layer.5 0.485076100 32.20246 RCP8.5
12 layer.6 0.494625800 32.16779 RCP8.5
13 layer.1 0.448782900 32.05137 RCP4.5
14 layer.2 0.458433400 32.01951 RCP4.5
15 layer.3 0.468094600 32.04347 RCP4.5
16 layer.4 0.477749200 32.23928 RCP4.5
17 layer.5 0.487547700 32.61044 RCP4.5
18 layer.6 0.497449000 32.14446 RCP4.5

ggplot(combined, aes(x, y, color = source)) +
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]

---

loading data from OP

```
RCP1pctCO2cumulative  <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "rowname RCP1pctCO2cumulative   Column
layer.1          0.000000000 30.62975
layer.2          0.006974906 30.29012
layer.3          0.013907599 30.43212
layer.4          0.021697436 30.70810
layer.5          0.030232970 30.38155
layer.6          0.038998084 30.34130")


RCP8.5cumulative  <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "rowname RCP8.5cumulative  Column1
layer.1        0.4475691 31.94422
layer.2        0.4569296 31.93002
layer.3        0.4663113 31.98923
layer.4        0.4756628 32.16458
layer.5        0.4850761 32.20246
layer.6        0.4946258 32.16779")



RCP4.5cumulative    <- read.table(
  header = T, 
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  text = "rowname RCP4.5cumulative  Column2
layer.1        0.4487829 32.05137
layer.2        0.4584334 32.01951
layer.3        0.4680946 32.04347
layer.4        0.4777492 32.23928
layer.5        0.4875477 32.61044
layer.6        0.4974490 32.14446")
```

Comment: Hi Jon Spring  Thank you for this response! Would this work if the number of rows differ across the four data frames? If so, could you please show a little more after the "mutate" part above, just to visualize what is happening beyond that? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this would just stack them. It would be helpful if you could include the output of `dput(head(RCP1pctCO2cumulative))` and same for another of the tables in the body of your question.

Comment: Updated answer using your given data. Would work the same regardless of length of each table, since we are combining them "vertically," into a longer collection of rows.

Comment: Hi Jon Spring - thanks for this response! I tried your method, too, and it worked! Finally, am trying to label x, y and title but am receiving errors and was hoping you could tell me what is causing it: ggplot(newestdata, aes(x,value,colour=L1)) + geom_smooth() + scale_color_manual(values=cols) + theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line() + ggtitle("Global model mean one-day maximum precipitation for various scenarios")) Error in element_line() + ggtitle("Global model mean one-day maximum precipitation for various scenarios") : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: `+ theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line()` needs a closing parenthesis before you move on to `+ggtitle...`

Comment: Hi Jon Spring - Thanks for the response - I tried that, like the following, but I end up with a parenthesis error:
ggplot(newestdata, aes(x,value,colour=L1)) + geom_smooth() + scale_color_manual(values=cols) + theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line()) + ggtitle("Global model mean one-day maximum precipitation for various scenarios"))
Error: unexpected ')' in "ggplot(newestdata, aes(x,value,colour=L1)) + geom_smooth() + scale_color_manual(values=cols) + theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line()) + ggtitle("Global model mea"

Comment: You have two `))` at the end in `various scenarios"))`

Comment: Hi Jon Spring - Fantastic! That works! Thank you so, so much! I will definitely give you several +1s above, since you kindly took the time to address two questions! :) Your help was greatly appreciated through all of this!