# How to change colors of lines of different datasets in ggplot and have a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend

I want to make a plot with a legend of two different datasets in the same plot

I first tried this:

```
df1 = data.frame(c11 = c(1:5), c12 = c(1:5))
df2 = data.frame(c21 = c(1:5), c22 = (c(1:5))^0.5)

ggplot() + geom_line(data=df1, aes(x=c11, y = c12), color= "red") + 
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=c21,y=c22), color = "blue")
```

Using this I get the color I want but no legend

Then I tried this:

```
ggplot() + geom_line(data=df1, aes(x=c11, y = c12, color= "DF1")) + 
  geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=c21,y=c22, color= "DF2"))
```

Using this I get a legend but not the correct colors. I then tried using
`scale_color_manual()` but I don´t know how to form an argument for 2 different datasets

I know there is a way but I do not seem to find it
Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))` ?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but for some reason, I got an error but now that I copied the code it worked. Maybe I wrote something wrong. thank you very much

Comment: In order to get a legend, you must combine your 2 datasets into one, then define color as a variable. See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525864/multiple-lines-each-based-on-a-different-dataframe-in-ggplot2-automatic-colori?rq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple lines each based on a different dataframe in ggplot2 - automatic coloring and legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525864/multiple-lines-each-based-on-a-different-dataframe-in-ggplot2-automatic-colori)

Comment: It's just more succinct to combine data.frames with similar columns, it isn't strictly necessary though.

Answer (score 0):

scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))